# What's the name for this connector?

Tags: batteries, components, identification, lithium-ion

Recently bought 3.7mAH li-ion batteries on ebay (it's labelled for use with RC toys, but I'm using it for DIY projects). Will need to buy the female adapter. Here are some pics:

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

EDIT: Well then, looks like I'll have to cut it off.

Comment: Eh. Diagonal cutters. But not across both wires at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2011982

That link has them talking about the proper PN for the Walkera connector (which is what you seem to have).

Here is a picture of the Walkera/Loku part that matches yours:
[image]

The part you have is equivalent to Molex PN 0510050200. You need Molex PN 51006-0200. Or you could buy the Walkera male part if you want to stick with that RC brand.

In case you're interested in how I got my answer, I googled "rc battery connector" and one of the first images had the Walkera connector. Visited the page for the name and went from there.

Comment: ah thanks. I googled the same and went through a bunch of images but they were all PSU-type connectors

Comment: Yeah I use Futaba servos so google might have used my past searches to give me different stuff. Glad I could help